# Can't remove top links Magento 1.9

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

Our clients want to display some customer links to top.links, e.g: Address Book, My Orders, etc. I used *prepare* tag.

```
<action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="sales">
            <label>My Orders</label>
            <url>sales/order/history/</url>
            <title>My Orders</title>
            <prepare>1</prepare>
            <urlParams/>
            <position>5</position>
 </action>
```

However, I try to use method *removeLinkByUrl* , I can't remove these links. I found *removeLinkByUrl()* method in *app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Template/Links.php*, we don't have code lines to remove links with *prepare* tag:

```
public function removeLinkByUrl($url)
{
    foreach ($this->_links as $k => $v) {
        if ($v->getUrl() == $url) {
            unset($this->_links[$k]);
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Any idea about this?

**Update:**
Using *prepare* tag will return with a base url. If I try to add

```
<action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url>**Our Magento site base url**/sales/order/history</url></action>
```

Our link will be removed.

Answer (score 1):

You should add another action (for removeLinkByUrl) to top.links, like so:

`<action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url>sales/order/history</url></action>`

Comment: Thanks! I try but I failed. Using *prepare* tag will return with a base url. If I try to add `<action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url>**Our Magento site base url**/sales/order/history</url></action>`. Our link will be removed.

Comment: You're trying to do it using base url/sales/order/history? And just /sales/order/history isn't working?

Comment: You take a look _app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Template/Links.php_. addLink() method with prepare = true will return with a base url. `'url'           => ($prepare ? $this->getUrl($url, (is_array($urlParams) ? $urlParams : array())) : $url)`. So, we cannot remove link by `<action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url>sales/order/history</url></action>`